# android webview scrolling not smooth, lags

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on a simple Android app that has only one activity, a WebView. It works very well on my phone (Android Version 7.1.2 Nougat), but I have received complaints from many users that the scrolling is not smooth and lags a bit (except on Google Pixel).

I've read many answers for this issue and implemented every one of them but it still lags. I've added the following lines of code:

On Android Manifest file:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

On MainActivity.java file:

```
webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Is there anything I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can help you

```
getWindow().setFlags(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

Comment: Nope, still lags.